# invalid UEFI volume when capturing AMI BIOS /ACPI 2.0

Tags: backup, bios, firmware, uefi

I want to backup BIOS. I use Universal BIOS Backup ToolKit V2.0.
[image]

Reading and backup are done without any error. When I want to open the captured BIOS  .rom using UEFITool.exe the error occurs:

[image]
and the message is displayed:

```
parseBios: one of volumes inside overlaps the end of data
```

CPU-Z info:
[image]

I think that BIOS I capture is somehow corrupted. How should I capture it properly?

EDIT:
[The backup file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMYtUEok8pHYeDkk6dNsOv-1lwFqQh0i/view?usp=sharing) produced by Universal BIOS Backup ToolKit.

Comment: The backup is parsed incorrectly because of flawed microcode header detection, UEFITool bugs [#181](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/issues/181) and [#180](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/issues/180), will be resolved in the next NE release.

Answer (score 2):

That Apollo Lake BIOS uses IFWI 2.0 layout for BIOS region (parsing of which is only supported by the very latest UEFITool NE).

Most IFWI 2.0 images have a [well-known bug](https://www.win-raid.com/t840f39-ME-Analyzer-Intel-Engine-Firmware-Analysis-Tool-Discussion-12.html#msg30782), that prevents UEFITool 0.2x from parsing them correctly. This bug is very popular, so UEFITool NE will get a workaround for it ([IFWI 2.0 support issue](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/issues/82)).

Comment: UEFITool Ne alpha 55 says:  
parseRawArea: one of volumes inside overlaps the end of data.  
parse: not a single Volume Top File is found, the image may be corrupted

Comment: I have appended the backup file to the question.